# Where is Spring Tool Suite's error log? ("See Error Log for more details")

Tags: spring-tool-suite

[Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools) gives me a cryptic error that also says:

> See Error Log for more details

**QUESTION**: Where can I find the error log of Spring Tool Suite?

- Nothing in Eclipse's "Console" view
- I launched STS from command line, but nothing special is shown on command line, some debug information but nothing that looks like an error

Comment: Go to "Show View" from the "Window" menu, and select the "Error View" from there. It will reveal more details.

Comment: @MartinLippert: Are you sure? Unfortunately STS does not have an "Error View" item in "Show View", even when searching within "Other..."

Comment: Yes, I am sure... :-) Go to "Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Error Log" (is called Error LOG, not Error VIEW, as I mentioned above, sorry for that)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Tutorial\sts-4.20.1.RELEASE\configuration>dir *.log
Volume in drive C is OSDisk
Volume Serial Number is 5003-F3AE

Directory of C:\Tutorial\sts-4.20.1.RELEASE\configuration

11/14/2023  09:18 PM               599 1700014699465.log
11/15/2023  08:21 AM               599 1700054484168.log
11/16/2023  08:04 AM               599 1700139854707.log
11/16/2023  09:21 AM               599 1700144485872.log
11/16/2023  01:34 PM               599 1700159685070.log
11/17/2023  08:32 AM               599 1700227943054.log
11/17/2023  08:44 AM               599 1700228691909.log
11/18/2023  01:15 PM               599 1700331333304.log
11/19/2023  10:40 AM               599 1700408452446.log
11/19/2023  11:59 AM               599 1700413167306.log
11/19/2023  12:28 PM               740 1700414886372.log
11/19/2023  12:30 PM               599 1700415005658.log
11/21/2023  02:06 PM               599 1700593584463.log
11/24/2023  12:36 PM               599 1700847385287.log
11/25/2023  08:45 AM               599 1700919949631.log
11/26/2023  08:49 AM               599 1701006547359.log
11/26/2023  02:58 PM               599 1701028737814.log
11/26/2023  05:30 PM               599 1701037831341.log
11/26/2023  05:32 PM               599 1701037968659.log
11/27/2023  07:45 AM               599 1701089100619.log
11/27/2023  01:58 PM               599 1701111522265.log
11/28/2023  08:35 AM               599 1701178532299.log
11/28/2023  10:09 AM               599 1701184175520.log
11/29/2023  02:23 PM               599 1701285816675.log
11/30/2023  11:33 AM               599 1701362009287.log
12/04/2023  12:37 PM               599 1701711463496.log
12/04/2023  03:41 PM               599 1701722482407.log
12/05/2023  08:33 AM               599 1701783221793.log
12/05/2023  10:08 AM               599 1701788921155.log
12/05/2023  11:43 AM               599 1701794591516.log
12/05/2023  03:18 PM               599 1701807535277.log
12/05/2023  03:18 PM               599 1701807535416.log
12/06/2023  08:33 AM               599 1701869604398.log
33 File(s)         19,908 bytes
0 Dir(s)  281,062,121,472 bytes free

C:\Tutorial\sts-4.20.1.RELEASE\configuration>

Comment: The fold "configuration" in the fold that you install STS (Spring Tool Suite) has log file. But it is not a error log file. Is the error log just exit in memory?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35367489)